# Html Agility Pack foreach loop error

Tags: c#, oop, html-agility-pack

```
string searchString = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "%20");
string url = "http://sometorrentsearchurl.com/search/" + searchString + "/0/99/401";

HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());

foreach (HtmlNode torrent in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
{
   foreach (HtmlNode title in torrent.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='detLink']"))
       {
          Label tTitle = new Label();
          tTitle.Text = title.InnerText;
          tTitle.Location = new Point(133, tHeightLoc);
          tTitle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
          tTitle.ForeColor = Color.White;
          tTitle.AutoSize = false;
          tTitle.Font = new Font("Arial", 10);
          tTitle.Size = new Size(347, 25);
          tTitle.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
          tTitle.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
          panel2.Controls.Add(tTitle);

          tHeightLoc += 45;
       }
 }
```

I am trying to get the list of torrents from a site and for every html `th` tag found I want to create some controls in my form with values taken from other children html tags, but this line returns an error `foreach (HtmlNode title in torrent.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='detLink']"))`

I want to know how to fix it because is the first time that I am using Html Agility Pack.

Comment: No need to share the error details, because we are mind readers.

Comment: @Oded Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Then the object you are trying to reference is null. On which line exactly does this happen?

Comment: @ChrisK `foreach (HtmlNode title in torrent.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='detLink']"))`

Comment: Could it be that `torrent` is null?

Comment: @ChrisK There is a list of torrents ... and it is in html ...

Comment: The variable torrent is probably null. Check it while debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here `torrent.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='detLink']"))`, it was a null selection an I fixed it like this `torrent.SelectNodes("//a[@class='detLink']"))`